# Using AsyncTask with multiple activities

Tags: android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask class and two activity classes. First activity handles authentication and second is for chatting.Now i want to share same AsyncTask with both activities without loosing connection to server.I tried it with each activity and it works fine but when i switch activities it keeps sticking  to first activity.I want to get results in both activities. What is the proper way to use AsyncTask class with multiple activities?
And what about using service instead of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try one host Activity with AsyncTask and two Fragments (authentication, chatting). Fragments will get result indirectly from the host Activity.

Be aware of [AsyncTask pitfalls](http://mgolokhov.github.io/processes_and_threads/).

In your case the cleaner way is to use service.